# React setState not executing within firestore add document promise resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing a list of items as documents in a firestore collection. When new items are added to the list they will stored in a separate variable in the component state but merged with an array of items already persisted to firestore.

The documents are only added to the firestore collection when a manual call to save them is invoked. The logic that is called when the save call is invoked is as follows:

```
if (this.state.unsavedNoteItems.length){
    let items = this.state.unsavedNoteItems.map(item => item) //make a local copy of unsaved items
    this.setState({unsavedNoteItems:[]}) //clear unsaved items array in component state
    items.map(item => {
        docRef.collection('items').add(item)
        .then(doc => {
            console.log("item saved: ", doc.id)
            //if item was added successfully, merge it into note Items
            this.setState((pState) => {noteItems: [...pState.noteItems,item]})
            console.log('state was set', item)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: ", error)
            //if item add failed, put is back in unsavedNoteItems list
            this.setState((pState) => {unsavedNoteItems: [...pState.unsavedNoteItems,item]})
        })
    })
}
```

In the resolver after the item is added, the `this.setState` does not update the UI, even though the changes have persisted.

I have resolved this by just creating a query snapshot but want to understand why the setState call does not update the UI. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(pState) => {noteItems: [...pState.noteItems,item]}` here `{ }` is not an object literal but a block statement.

```js
const iReturnUndefined = value => {a: value}
const iReturnObject = value => ({a: value})

console.log(iReturnUndefined('a'))
console.log(iReturnObject('a'))
```

You need to wrap it with `()` to make it an object initializer expression

```
if (this.state.unsavedNoteItems.length){
    let items = this.state.unsavedNoteItems.map(item => item) //make a local copy of unsaved items
    this.setState({unsavedNoteItems:[]}) //clear unsaved items array in component state
    items.map(item => {
        docRef.collection('items').add(item)
        .then(doc => {
            console.log("item saved: ", doc.id)
            // NB! 1
            this.setState(pState => ({noteItems: [...pState.noteItems,item]}))
            console.log('state was set', item)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Error: ", error)
            // NB! 2
            this.setState(pState => ({unsavedNoteItems: [...pState.unsavedNoteItems,item]}))
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: How does this even transpile ?

Comment: @Logar It is syntacticly valid. JS do have labels. :)